# displaying htm contents in browser via Response.Writefile in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm working on a site that I've inherited that's built with ASP.Net, which I'm only slightly familiar with.  One of the pages allows for a link to a document (word or pdf) that, when clicked on, prompts the user to save or open the file, but does not reveal the true path of the file.  This way it prevents users from pasting a url to a file - the link is to an aspx file that checks for a valid session, and then retrieves the file.

Anyway, because there's a lot of legacy code, I need to do this with a bunch of static htm files as well, however these files need to be displayed rather than prompting the user to save them, which is what happens now.  I tried changing the content type to application/text, application/html, text/html, etc. and that didn't work, then tried adding a response header of  content-disposition inline.  When I do that, build, and try linking to the file, I get a couple of runtime exceptions:

```
[FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDecimal(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat) +206
Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToLong(String Value) +110

[InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "inline; filename=\" + myFile + " to type  'Long' is not valid.]
Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToLong(String Value) +428
cmswebasp.CMSModdoclinks.DownloadFile(String file) +1704
cmswebasp.CMSModdoclinks.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) +625
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Here's a snippet of code from the page:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" & file)


Dim fi As New FileInfo(myFile)
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length)

Dim contentType As String = ""
Dim fileExt As String = file.Split(".")(1)

Select Case fileExt

Case "htm"
contentType = "application/text"
Case Else
contentType = "application/octet-stream"
End Select

Response.ContentType = contentType
Response.WriteFile(myFile)
```

Do I have to do something with an htmlwriter object or something?  Can't I just have it open a new browser window with the file displaying or does it have to prompt the user if used in this way??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrap the full page (.aspx) approach in place of using a generic handler (.ashx). An .aspx page is going to do a lot of built-in loading to initialize all the state that would normally be used in an ASP.NET web page, while the generic handler only initializes the bare minimum to send output back out to the client.

You will need to also implement `System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState` to get your session state when using a generic handler, as it does not load the session state by default.

An example:

```
Public Class FileWrapper
    Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState

    Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
        ' Validate session...

        ' Set output content type based on extension of requested file
        Dim fileName As String = context.Request.QueryString("file")
        Dim fileExt As String = fileName.Split("."c)(1).ToLowerInvariant()
        Select Case fileExt
            Case "htm", "html"
                context.Response.ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html
            Case Else
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & fileName)
                context.Response.ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet
        End Select
        context.Response.WriteFile(fileName)
    End Sub

    ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Note: If hosting on IIS 7, you will need to remove any `<httpHandler>` registrations from `<system.web>` and register them instead as `<handler>` registrations in `<system.webServer>`.

Such as (correct as necessary to use your namespace):

```
<system.webServer>
  <!-- For IIS 7 -->
  <handlers>
    <add name="FileWrapperHandler" path="FileWrapper.ashx" verb="*" type="MyNamespace.FileWrapper"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Another Note: If you *are* developing for a IIS 7 host using Integrated pipeline (default for IIS 7), then I would suggest using (and installing if necessary) the IIS Express option for your web project. This would be found going into Properties for your web project, the Web tab from left, then in the Servers section, select Use Local IIS Web Server radio button, and check Use IIS Express below.

[image: Use IIS Express]

This will put your development environment more in sync with how your production environment will behave.

Comment: Sorry, finally got around to implementing this and it works like a charm - I used code from http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx in order to feed the correct filename into the handler.

Comment: My only problem, however, is that even I'm implementing IRequiresSessionState as you show above, I'm able to access the url and thus the file without being logged in...  Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Never mind, I guess I just needed to write the conditional code that would prevent the user from accessing the page if their session variable wasn't set.

Comment: So this was working fine on my local instance of VS with the temp web server, but when transferring it up to our server and having them update the dll, it doesn't seem to work there.  Initially it was giving parsing errors (unable create type X where X is the class name I gave my handler).  Then after the admin did some more updating, it started to work, but only prompts to save and not open doc files.  None of this happens on my local instance.  Are their web.config settings to look out for in relation to this?

Comment: @LeviWallach What version of IIS is on the host? I didn't have to add anything locally, either, but I seem to recall there being a web.config entry for IIS 6.  Looking into that, and will update answer based on what I find.

Comment: @LeviWallach Sorry the solution is not-so-simple after all. I included some steps that should help resolve current issue, as well as reveal issues locally, first, before going to production (assuming production is running IIS 7+). If the opposite is true (production is IIS 6 or below), then make sure Use IIS Express is *not* checked.

Comment: Thanks so much!  We are using IIS7.  I did not know we needed to add handler entries in web.config, so will see about getting that done.  I'll see what I can do about installing IIS Express as well, hopefully that will solve issues that don't crop up locally and then surprise me when they don't work on the server!

Comment: I tried adding the handlers section to web.config & that didn't work. Could be I entered wrong parameters, but in any case, I decided at least for now to use our old aspx redirect method for documents that are ok to open/save outside of the browser, but use ashx for inline html. Works great. However, there's one remaining issue: we have Word documents that link to these redirect urls. When the links go to aspx redirects they work as expected but with the ashx they don't recognize any existing browser session and the user needs to re-login every time they click a link to one of these.

Comment: Based on this page (http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) I wonder if the solution is in adding url mappings to web.config?  Or do you think that referencing the handlers is necessary instead (or both)?

Comment: @LeviWallach The UrlMapping is just essentially a static redirect. Assuming you are going directly to the url of your .ashx page, a redirect is unnecessary. As for Word documents, the generic handler we created will not work. It is setup as a very bare wrapper, simply loading the content of the file and dumping it straight out to the http response stream.

Comment: I see, so in that case, should we try to pursue the aspx redirect I started with to display html inline in order to retain session information, or is there a way to enhance the generic handler to maintain it in the desired way?

Comment: @LeviWallach I've updated my answer. See if the new code accomplishes what you are trying to do. I'm curious what is causing session issues with the ashx file. Are you able to set break-points and check the session locally? Everything should be in order, and shouldn't depend upon the requested file type. Please check again with the updated code and comment back or grab me in a chat.

Comment: did not see you in chat.  I would update my code with your new code, but I'm afraid the only thing that will potentially solve is the issue of not being able to use the ashx method for doc files (non-html).  The overriding issue is that when the page gets summoned via the hyperlink from a Word document, it's redirecting.  I have a conditional statement that encloses the code within the sub that: 'If Not context.Session("THE_USER") Is Nothing Then'.  This gets detected as false and so the redirection occurs and the code inside is never executed...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11066/discussion-between-guthmd-and-levi-wallach)

Answer (score 0):

The server might be throwing out your manually-set content-type header when you call `Response.WriteFile()`.  Find out what the actual content-type header is when the client receives it.  [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) will tell you if you look under its Net tab.

If this is the case, try setting `Response.ContentType` after calling `Response.WriteFile()`.  Alternatively, you could try reading the file into a string and use `Response.Write()` instead of `WriteFile`.

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion, it appears that you may be best served using a lobotomized `Page` after all, instead of a generic handler, due to the possibility of users coming to the site via links within Word documents or other sources outside the browser.

We've found that the aspx page is able to recover session in this instance, whereas the ashx does not. Thus, I am providing code for an aspx solution:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ' Validate session...

    ' Set output content type based on extension of requested file
    Dim fileName As String = Request.QueryString("file")
    Dim fileExt As String = fileName.Split("."c)(1).ToLowerInvariant()
    Select Case fileExt
        Case "htm", "html"
            Response.ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Html
        Case Else
            Response.ClearHeaders()
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & fileName)
            Response.ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet
    End Select
    Response.WriteFile(fileName)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.Close()
End Sub
```

It doesn't matter whatever is placed in the aspx markup itself, since none of that will get rendered anyway.

Just a note that this may cause some log entries on the web host about trying to "access a closed stream" since we have closed the response stream, but the page will continue processing as usual. That's one of the prices to pay for essentially hijacking the normal page flow.

Comment: I got this working so that it will serve html inline vs. other files as attachments.  However, the behavior I was experiencing before (session stickiness), I'm not seeing today.  Hopefully I wasn't just imagining it!  At this point it doesn't look possible, but if there is some workaround, I'd love to know!